# Add two csv file to a list in Java

Tags: java, csv

My Java program has a superclass (`ProgettoBase`) and two underclasses (`ProgettoCorpo` and `ProgettoOre`). I must copy two different csv files (progetti_ora.csv and progetti_corpo.csv) to a list but I can't see the elements of the list when I launch the program.

```
public void readFile () {

    List<String> projects = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("My list is: " + projects);

    //read 1 progetti_ora
    String csvFile = "progetti_ora.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ";";

    //read 2 progetti_corpo
    String csvFileDue = "progetti_corpo.csv";
    BufferedReader brDue = null;
    String lineDue = "";
    String cvsSplitByDue = ";";

    //read file 1
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] vote = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            for(String s : vote)
                System.out.println("List one: " + s);
            for(int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
                projects.add(vote[x].toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("OK1");
    //read file 2
    try {
        brDue = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileDue));
        while ((lineDue = brDue.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] voteDue = lineDue.split(cvsSplitByDue);
            for(String t : voteDue)
                System.out.println("Lista file due: " + t);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("OK2");  
}
```

Comment: What exactly *can* you see?

Comment: You didn't add any line to your list from file2. Try printing out the size of your  list after two files insertion.

Comment: `can't see the elements of the list when I launch the program` What do you mean can't see? See how? See where? See when?

Comment: Either your didn't have lines in the parsed files, either the way of splitting lines is wrong. You can add some lines of your csv files ?